# Python BeautifulSoup issue parsing table

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Hi I am using beautifulsoup to parse tables in the following website, but not all the rows are getting returned. I looking for article tags (http://itp.ne.jp/result/?kw=%92J%98e%8E%95%89%C8%83N%83%8A%83j%83b%83N)

```
url = 'http://itp.ne.jp/result/?kw=%92J%98e%8E%95%89%C8%83N%83%8A%83j%83b%83N'
page = requests.get(url)
prefsoup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

art= prefsoup.find_all("article")

print(art)

[<article>
<section class="noimage">
<h4 class="clearfix">
<a class="blackText" href="/shop/KN0114031400001406/" target="_blank">谷脇歯科クリニック</a>
<a class="itrademark24" href="/stats_click/?s_bid=KN0114031400001406&amp;s_sid=FSP-LSR-001&amp;s_fr=V09&amp;s_ck=C12&amp;s_acd=7" target="_blank"><img alt="付加価値情報" src="/img/pc/shop/icon_itrade_7.gif"/></a>
</h4>
<p><span class="inlineSmallHeader">住所</span> 〒060-0042　北海道札幌市中央区大通西５丁目 <a class="boxedLink navigationLink" href="/shop/KN0114031400001406/map.html" target="_blank">地図・ナビ</a></p>
<p><span class="inlineSmallHeader">TEL</span>
<a class="whiteboxicon popup_04" href="/guide/phonemark.html">(代)</a>
<b>011-213-1184</b></p>
<p>
<span class="inlineSmallHeader">URL</span>
http://taniwaki-dental.com</p></section></article>]
```

However it is missing the last paragraph with the email information

```
<p><span class="inlineSmallHeader">EMAIL</span>
taniwaki@kzh.biglobe.ne.jp<!-- br-->            
</p>
```

Moreover len(art) returns a 2, and art[1] returns an index out of range error.

Tried several pages and got the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parser `html5lib` instead of `html.parser` and it will work like a charm. You just need to change the following line of code -

```
prefsoup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
```

to -

```
prefsoup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html5lib")
```

Of course, you will need to install the `html5lib` using `pip install html5lib`.

Check this as well - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: I had to add the encoding, but it did work as a charm !!    BeautifulSoup(pref.content,"html5lib", from_encoding="Shift_JIS")

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if it worked for you :)